# Short Story Search: Blind girl, kidnapped by the devil; page of book carved onto her skin

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Here is the gist of the story. A blind girl is kidnapped by the devil to have a entire page of a book written on her. There is an entire room of people who have other pages carved into them too, they make up the entire book. Really gruesome story which I read once.

Comment: There is a list [somewhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) — also [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) — of things that you should strive to include in any such [tag:story-identification] question.  Cheers!

Comment: Total guess: "The Devil's Own Crayons" by Theresa Monsour.

Answer (score 8):

I have this story in an anthology! The girl sold her soul for an erotic forbidden experience, as her life was sad and lonely. It is **"[The Braille Encyclopaedia](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42699)"** (1991) by Grant Morrison! I have it in an anthology called *[Hotter Blood: More Tales of Erotic Horror](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/490205)* (1991). Excellent story! I do recommend the *[Hot Blood](https://www.goodreads.com/series/269806-hot-blood)* anthologies...some super good stuff in them!

Comment: Providing citation helps other users to locate the specific text you're referring to.